# Relationships Laravel OneToOne?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent, laravel-5.3, relacionamento

Estou fazendo uns exercícios, mais existe um porem onde não consigo entender o por que não esta funcionando quando eu faço com outro nome no método. Tenho um método no `Model Location`, onde ele faz o `relationships` de `OneToOne`.

Quando eu chamo o método com o nome simples ele funciona, mais quando eu chamo o método com o nome composto ele da `null`.

#### Model Location

```
public function countryInverso()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Country::class);
}
```

#### Controller OneToOne

```
public function umPraUmReverso()
{
    $location = Location::where('latitude', 54)->get()->first();
    $country = $location->countryInverso;
    dd($country);
}
```

Dessa forma retorna do `dd()` como nulo
Agora se eu colocar dessa forma

#### Model Location

```
public function country()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Country::class);
}
```

#### Controller OneToOne

```
public function umPraUmReverso()
{
    $location = Location::where('latitude', 54)->get()->first();
    $country = $location->country;
    dd($country);
}
```

Dessa ultima forma ele volta pra mim os dados, porque, com o nome no método `countryInverso` não funciona e somente com o nome `country` funciona?

Comment: como é nome da a chave estrangeira ?

Comment: country_id e o nome da minha chave estrangeira

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos analisar o que a [documentação do Laravel sobre relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships) pode nos dizer para resolver o seu problema.

Em um relacionamento [`One-to-One`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships) há o seguinte exemplo:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Phone extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

No exemplo acima, o *Eloquent* tentará combinar `user_id` do *model* `Phone` com `id` do *model* `User`. Mas como ele faz isso???

O *Eloquent* pressupõem o nome da **chave estrangeira padrão**, examinando o **nome do método de relacionamento** e apenas adiciona ao nome do método o `_id`. Isso quer dizer que a chave estrangeira, para o *Elloquent*, contida na tabela `Phone` no banco de dados será `user_id`.

Este é o motivo do seu problema. Sua chave estrangeira é country_id e só funciona caso o método de relação se chamar country. Qualquer outro nome não irá funcionar. No momento que você alterou o nome do método para `countryInverso` o *Elloquent* determinou que o nome da chave estrangeria seria `countryinverso_id` e ao buscar tal parâmetro no banco a resposta foi `null`.

**Como resolver este problema?**

No entanto, se a chave estrangeira do *model* `Phone` não for user_id, você pode passar um nome de chave personalizado como o segundo argumento para o método `belongsTo`:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'foreign_key');
}
```

Desta forma você poderá trabalhar com o nome do método como quiser e manter o nome da chave estrangeira como está. Seu caso ficaria assim:

```
public function countryInverso()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Country::class, 'country_id');
}
```

Comment: Perfeita a explicação. Super grato.